# How come if a = b, then b = a?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Let me explain. I have the following piece of code :

```js
let a = [1, 2, 3];
let b = a;
b.splice(2, 1);
console.log("a: " + a);
console.log("b: " + b);
```

I would have expected to get something like :

```
a = [1, 2, 3];
b = [1, 2];
```

However, after running the code, it turns out both "a" and "b" equal [1, 2]. I am really confused, since "b" should only have been assigned a copy of "a", instead of acting as some sort of a pointer to "a". I wonder if it is because JS handles arrays (objects) differently of if it is something specific to the splice function. I would also like to know how you would bypass that odd behavior.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: `b` references `a`, it is not a copy. Someone will find the dupe.

Comment: *"since "b" should only have been assigned a copy of "a"* Why ? Where are you copying ?

Comment: BTW copying would have been `let b = a.slice();`

Comment: duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/a/6605700/4267015

Comment: @DenysSéguret what do you mean?

Comment: You say *"b should only have been assigned a copy of a"* but your code shows b being assigned a, not a copy.

Comment: @DenysSéguret yeah no but how would b = a.splice() assign b a copy of a

Comment: splice != slice   Read the linked QA

Comment: @DenysSéguret oh, sorry, my mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first line you are creating the array and pointing `a` variable to that array.
In the second line `let b = a;`, here you are pointing `b` variable to the `a` array again.

So both `a` and `b` variables will be pointing to the same array. When you do a change to the array, both `a` and `b` values will be changed.